# In ^(?=.*[a-z]{2,}).{8,}$ this regex for atleast 2 lower case characters. TeSt@12345 does not work though it has 2 lower case characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, regex

I have a regex for at least 2 lower-case characters `^(?=.*[a-z]{2,}).{8,}$`

This works if lower-case characters are right next to each other : `Test@12345` ;
But does not work for `TeSt@12345` , where lower-case characters are not next to each other.

How do I make sure it works in both the above cases ?

Comment: Use `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})`

Comment: `[a-z]{2,}` means there are two lower case letters *next to each other*. In your example, there's a capital letter between them, they aren't next to each other.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, T,J this solved it and I understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2}).{8,}$`

This makes the `{2}` apply to the whole "anything followed by a lower-case letter" sequence.

Comment: Along with Wiktor ans T.J's fix this also works for any one referring.